# Build Boost (using b2) on Windows, but /MTd instead of /MDd?

Tags: windows, debugging, visual-c++, boost, static

I'm building Boost 1.72 on Windows, as part of a product build.  I'm trying to build everything /MTd and, except for Boost, I've been successful.  Unfortunately, though I've added "link=static" to the b2 command line, b2 insists upon building /MDd.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to persuade b2 to build debug/static, rather than debug/dynamic?

Comment: Though b2's results suggest that it is building what I've requested (debug and static):

`bin.v2\libs\filesystem\build\msvc-14.1\debug\address-model-64\link-static\threading-multi\libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib`

internally, the library contains (for each .obj, I presume):

 `/FAILIFMISMATCH:"RuntimeLibrary=MD_DynamicRelease"`

This is despite having the following environment variable defined:

`export CL=" /D_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL#0 /DRuntimeLibrary#MTd_StaticDebug /MTd"`